# Is Skype available for all Android flavors or just Verizon?

Tags: voip, skype

I see that Skype offers an Android version, but it only works on Verizon? Fring used to connect to Skype, but now it looks like they don't. Is there no Skype client for Android?

Comment: See also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9664/can-i-install-skype-on-my-xperia

Answer (score 13):

Skype is avaiable now for everyone on the Market, in case you are still looking!

Comment: Android 2.1 or later required.

Comment: Press release: http://about.skype.com/press/2010/10/android.html

Comment: As of today...Skype is not working on my ATT Samsung Galaxy-S Captivate. Fails to download...and others are complaining of problems.

Answer (score 2):

As of Skype 2.1 for Android (August 4, 2011), according to the [Skype Blog](http://blogs.skype.com/garage/2011/08/skype_21_for_android_more_devi.html).

The following Android devices are supported:

- Acer A5
- HTC Desire (2.2)
- HTC Desire HD
- HTC Evo 3D
- HTC Evo 4G
- HTC Flyer
- HTC Incredible S
- HTC Sensation
- HTC Thunderbolt - Verizon (2.2) (US only)
- LG Revolution - Verizon (2.2) (US only)
- Samsung Droid Charge - Verizon (2.2) (US only)
- Samsung Galaxy S
- Samsung Galaxy S II
- Samsung Galaxy Tab
- Sony Ericsson Xperia mini pro
- Sony Ericsson Xperia PLAY
- Sony Ericsson Xperia ray

Answer (score 1):

Right now skype for android is limited to VZW, but you aren't missing much. You can't use it to make skype out calls over a data connection, only skype to skype calls.  You can make skype out calls but VZW redirects the call over their voice network so it uses your minutes. Also, you can't use it over wifi, only on 3G. I believe VZW is behind all these restrictios, and I believe that the carrier restrictions aren't from skype either.  Most carriers will block the app unless its gutted like the skype app for VZW.  If you want a full featured skype app, don't hold your breath. I suspect the carriers will continue to work dilligently to f#@k up the experience. If you are looking to make data calls, look into finding a good SIP service and use SIPdroid.  You could also try frings new fring out service but I'm not very optomistic about that one.

**Update:** [It's now possible to make Skype Out calls over 3G with some hacks](http://lifehacker.com/5658262/make-skype-calls-over-3g-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make skype calls over wifi you can use [Fring](http://www.fring.com/android/) or [Nimbuzz](http://www.nimbuzz.com/en/android/download), both should be available in the market. I think you can also do calls over 3G but YMMV and it will eat into your data plan like a fat kit in a chocolate warehouse.

If you are on Verizon Wireless in the US or on Three in the UK (Possibly elsewhere) you can download an official skype app that only uses data for presence (who's logged in etc), when you want to make a skype call it calls a toll free number which is then redirected to Skype so it's not using your Data allowance and not killing the network for others. I don't know about the US but in the Uk this only works over 3g and will often fail to work if you have wireless enabled and are within range of a Wifi network.

Using this App on Three(UK) you can make Skype out calls and even configure your phone to automatically use Skype for international phone calls instead of just dialling the number normally.

Comment: Skype has blocked Fring and Nimbuzz now, and presumably any other client that used to work.

Answer (score 1):

There was an official Skype Lite app available on international Android Markets for quite a while (it was definitely on the UK Market at one time as I had it on my old phone), but they've pulled that totally now, and as far as I know it is literally only available to one carrier in one country, which seems like a bizarre decision.

Comment: See this other question for the various Skype apps and options available now depending on your phone model and what your phone network allows http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9664/can-i-install-skype-on-my-xperia

Answer (score 0):

Not until Skype opens up their app on other carriers. Which rumors keep coming out that it will happen soon, but hasn't yet.

[XDA has some threads on attempting to get Skype working on non VZW phones](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=5980386#post5980386), but no dice.