# Can I install Skype on my xperia?

Tags: installation, skype, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10

I want to install Skype on my xperia x10 but I cannot find it in the market
when I go to [Skype.com/m](http://skype.com/m) and try to download it, I get the following message:

> item not found

A friend of mine who has a Nokia C5 was able to install it.

How can I install it?

Comment: Doesn't the C5 run Symbian? Skype could be region-restricting Android phones differently than Symbian ones. Regardless, the Xperia X10 is not listed under their [supported Verizon devices](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/get-skype/on-your-mobile/skype-mobile/android/), so that's why you can't get it directly from their site.

Comment: @elder note that for people outside the US there's a different page, that only has Android 2.1 as a requirement and doesn't care about Verizon or supported handsets http://www.skype.com/intl/en/get-skype/on-your-mobile/download/skype-for-android/

Comment: @GAThrawn: Hm, you're right. I think I was confused when the OP said he tried to download it from skype.com because the non-Verizon page just redirects to the Market. The US Verizon one lets you enter your phone number to actually get a download from them. At least I assume it gives you a direct download...I don't have a VZW phone.

Comment: @GAThrawn i went to the link u provided.but i got >the item cannot be installed in ur device's country

Comment: according to https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?&answer=138294 Morocco doesn't have its own Android Market, I think Skype only targets specific country Markets and doesn't go into the "Rest of the world" Market. Skype's FAQs (see comments in my answer below) say to go to getjar.com if Skype isn''t found in your country's Market

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are regional and phone network restrictions for Skype. They may well be different for Nokia phones than Android phones, and your friend may not be on the same phone network as you.

There (is now) one official Skype app in the Play Store, and one I know of that isn't in Play Store:

- [Skype on Three](http://ask3.three.co.uk/srvs/cgi-bin/webisapi.dll/,/?new,kb=mobile,ts=mobile,t=casedoc.tem,case=obj%282011%29,varset_username=Mobile%3amobileUser)- Three UK customers only, follow directions on the linked page to get it
- [Skype](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.skype.raider) - requires Android 2.1+, works on all phone networks (outside of the US) where your phone network allows it.

The above options for finding Skype in the Play Store only work [if your country has its own Play Store](https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?&answer=138294), if your country currently uses the "Rest of the World" Store, then you won't be able to find Skype. According to [Skype's FAQ](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10653/How-can-I-get-Skype-on-my-Android-phone#3), if this is the case then you should go to [GetJar.com](http://www.getjar.com/) and download Skype from there.

Assuming you're not in a country/network that's blocking Skype then your problem may be the Android OS version on your phone, I think most Xperia x10's are still running Android 1.6 and the normal Skype app requires that you be running Android 2.1 or newer.

I think most countries have an Eclair (Android 2.1) upgrade for X10's, check what Android version your phone is running, and then find out if an upgrade is available.

Comment: thank you..how can i know im not country/network that's blocking Skype? (im in Morocco btw) and i have android 2.2

Comment: @astro According to the Skype FAQs https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10653/How-can-I-get-Skype-on-my-Android-phone#3  `The Android Market only distributes applications in certain countries, so it’s possible that your location isn’t supported. To find a full list of supported locations, please visit Android Market Developer Help.

If you live in a country that's not listed,  then you can still download Skype for your Android phone from GetJar.com. Simply search for "Skype" and download it for free.`

Comment: If it really is an Android Market thing, here's a listing of all countries with their own Android Market, and which one's get the "International, free-apps only" Market https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?&answer=138294

Comment: getjar doesnt recognise my phone :(

Comment: I live in Australia, and can't download 'Skype for au'. From the app description, I think 'Skype for au' is for a [Japanese provider named au](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Au_%28mobile_phone_company%29), not Australian.

Comment: @LieRyan thanks, corrected. That'll teach me to make assumptions without reading carefully enough!