# How can I install Skype on my NexusOne phone?

Tags: installation, skype

I search for `Skype` in Android Market application and cannot find it. I live in Vietnam.

Comment: See also this previous question on various International options for installing Skype: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9664/can-i-install-skype-on-my-xperia/9666#9666

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Skype publish their app directly into specific country's Android Markets, they don't publish it to the "Rest of the world Market", [Vietnam doesn't have its own Market](https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?&answer=138294), it uses the "Rest of The World Market".

[Skype's FAQ](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10653/How-can-I-get-Skype-on-my-Android-phone#3) says:

> Why can’t I download Skype from the
>   Android Market?
>
> The Android Market only distributes
>   applications in certain countries, so
>   it’s possible that your location isn’t
>   supported. To find a full list of
>   supported locations, please visit
>   Android Market Developer Help.
>
> If you live in a country that's not
>   listed,  then you can still download
>   Skype for your Android phone from
>   GetJar.com. Simply search for “Skype”
>   and download it for free.

Answer (score -1):

You can search for Skype on the Android Market or you can download the APK file directly from the Skype website, click [here](http://skype.org/intl/en-us/get-skype/on-your-mobile/download/skype-for-android/).

Comment: Please note that in my OP I said I can't find it on Android Market