# Is Skype available for the Motorola Xoom?

Tags: skype, motorola-xoom

Is Skype available for the Motorola Xoom?

Comment: Please, give some more details. A quick guess... If Skype is unavailable in Market, then probably you need to uncheck "Settings->Application->Fast boot" option.

Comment: I just want to use Skype on Motorola Xoom

Comment: I just want to help you. Could you please answer my questions above? I mean, provide some more details.

Comment: See alist of the various available Android Skype versions and where to get them from on this previous question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9664/can-i-install-skype-on-my-xperia note that because a lot of phone networks don't like Skype, it may be your network or country that stops you seeing it in the Market, not just your phone type.

Answer (score 4):

I recently (two nights ago) installed Skype on my Xoom, and it appears to work fine, with chat, video, and audio calling available.

This was on the UK market, Wifi version (so no provider issues), stock 3.2.

[This is the market item I have installed.](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.skype.raider)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it **is** compatible, but depending on which country you're in and how tight the laws are there, you may not be able to download Skype. However, there is an app called **Market Helper** which is for ROOTED devices which allows you to fake your location and download the app.