# Can't install skype on android 2.2

Tags: 2.2-froyo, skype

I'm using http://www.midoblesim.com/product_info.php?manufacturers_id=&products_id=483 and i can't install skype.It says that it's not matching, but still it is downloading it from the market. I gived you that link becouse this isn't an original, android phone, it's some Chinese stuff. But however, how can i solve the problem and install skype and run it correctly ?

Answer (score 4):

According to the web page that you linked, your phone has the following specs:

- mtk6516 416 MHz CPU
- 512 MB ROM
- 256 MB RAM
- Screen HVGA 800 x 480

The Skype FAQ says:

> [**What do I need to run Skype on my Android phone?**](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10653/How-can-I-get-Skype-on-my-Android-phone#2)
>
> To run Skype on your Android phone, you will need a supported phone
>   running Android OS version 2.1 or above with least 27MB of free memory
>   space on your handset and 600Mhz or more processing power. The
>   supported screen resolutions are 320x240, 240x400, 320x480, 800x480
>   and 850x480.

So it looks like the app doesn't support your phone's CPU (which oddly seems to be slower than the very earliest Android phones like the G1).

There is more than one official Skype app, it's possible that the one you're using isn't compatible with your phone, but another one might be. See the links in this question to find the Skype apps [Can I install Skype on my xperia?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9664/can-i-install-skype-on-my-xperia/9666#9666)

Comment: It looks like a knockoff company stole the name of an LG device to trick people.

Comment: @MatthewRead oh definitely, doesn't even look like an LG Optimus 3D (and is very obviously missing the second rear camera lens that helps define the "3D" part of the real thing's name) the case reminds me more of a knock-off Nexus One than an Optimus.