# need to install gtalk on my HCL X1 tab and also Skype

Tags: google-talk, skype

My tab uses 2.3.3 android version and I need to install Gtalk and Skype. As I read thro threads only after 2.3.4 gtalk is available. But any methods available for Gtalk on 2.3.3? also on skype
Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Talk is available for most Android versions, and in fact is pre-installed on all Google-authorised Android devices that have the Android Market and GMail installed (because both of those apps rely  on Talk to do their authentication and communication). It may just be called "Talk" on your device rather than "Google Talk" or "Gtalk".

If you're talking about [Google Voice](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.android.apps.googlevoice), then that app is available to all devices using Android 1.6 and higher, but you can currently only use the service within the US.

Skype use is blocked by some phone networks, but is generally available otherwise if you're outside the US, see [this previous answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/9666/156) for some of the options.