# Does Skype video work on a Samsung Galaxy 10.1?

Tags: skype, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

Can Skype be used for video calling on a Samsung Galaxy 10.1?

I have been googling, but the results are not clear, for example, the official [Skype Blog](http://blogs.skype.com/garage/2011/08/skype_21_for_android_more_devi.html) says that Skype 2.1 supports the Samsung Galaxy Tab, but it is not clear if this means that it works with both the 7" and 10.1" versions.

*Update: as of early 2012, Skype does work on most Android tablets.*

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/what-is-the-deal-with-skype-on-android

Comment: @al-everet that question is less specific, and still doesn't have the answer.

Comment: There is an answer there with a list of the current devices that can run Skype. Rather than pepper the site with dozens of questions like "Does Skype run on (Device X)" we'd prefer to have a canonical question like "What devices does Skype run on".

Comment: @Al-Everett Are you referring to [the answer that I posted](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/what-is-the-deal-with-skype-on-android/12903#12903)? If so, please note that it is the same information linked to in my answer above, and it does not answer the question because "Samsung Galaxy Tab" is on the list, without reference to model.

Comment: You seem to have a lot invested in proving me "wrong". I posted the link because the two questions cover similar ground and I wanted to see if anyone agreed. Obviously I'm not entirely convince they _are_ duplicates because, as a Moderator, if I thought that I just would have closed the question. I suggested it might be a duplicate; you've offered your reasons for why you think it isn't. Leave it at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official Skype app currently does not support video on NVIDIA Tegra 2 chipsets, according to their [FAQ](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA11019/How-do-I-make-video-calls-with-Skype-for-Android):

> * This specifically does not include some tablets that use the Tegra 2 chipset (e.g. Android tablets and Motorola Atrix do not support video calling).

From what I read on various forums, a test version that does work on Honeycomb tablets sporting Tegra 2 has been seen floating around in Youtube videos, so it should be coming to official channels shortly.

Comment: is it possible to obtain one of the test versions? Any ideas on how long 'shortly' is?

Comment: I haven't seen one yet, but chances are it will appear on XDA first.

Answer (score 2):

You have go into the settings then enable video calling.

Comment: Confirmed, Skype video calling works on Tab 10.1 after this.