# How can I find out what devices support Skype video calling over Wi-Fi?

Tags: wi-fi, skype

How can I find out what devices support Skype video calling over Wi-Fi?  (I'm particularly interested in tablets.)

Comment: Shopping questions are considered off-topic on this site.  Since new Android devices are being released on an almost daily basis, this would be a never-ending list that gets outdated just as often.

Comment: @Chahk ok, fair enough and thanks for explaining the downvote. I will try to make the question more generic

Comment: Thanks for the attempt to fix it, kristof, but unfortunately a list will just get out of date (one of the major problems with shopping recommendations as well).  [This question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/what-is-the-deal-with-skype-on-android) has answers pointing to official sources and Lie's answer also points to something official.  I'll rewrite this to ask how to find out, perhaps, rather than asking for a list.  Hope that's OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Skype application description in the market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.skype.raider&hl=en) lists the list of devices that supports video calling. As of Skype 2.5.0.108, video calling is supported on these tablets:

- Samsung Galaxy Tab 7 (Wifi, Verizon, Sprint, Plus)
- HTC Flyer
- Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (T-Mobile)
- Acer Iconia Tablet (A500)
- Motorola Xoom
- Acer Iconia Smart

Devices that are not listed may still be able to do video calling, but Skype says that the video quality may not be as good as on supported devices. Check out Skype's application description page for the latest list of supported devices.

Comment: thanks @Lie, I was just looking at the market description when your answer appeared. The interesting part in that description is _Devices that are not listed may still be able to do video calling_. I wonder if there exists an unofficial list.